# Mongoose: issues populating an object in an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have the following three models:

```
var User = {
first_name: String,
last_name: String,
}

var Student = {
role = String,
user = {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
groups = [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}],
}

var Group = {
name = String,
students = [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student'}],
}
```

My express get method looks like:

```
router.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res){
    Group.find().populate('students').exec(function(err, groups){
      res.json(groups);
    });
```

My json object returns the array of student objects a that are populated, but i am only receiving a user._id from within each of the student objects.  How can I also get the user object to populate? Any info would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: Why did you separate the key and values in the Student and Group objects with "=" instead ":" ?

Comment: My mistake, just a typo. I used colon's in the actual models :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate across multiple levels:

```
router.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res){
    Group
      .find()
      .populate({
        path: 'students',
        // Get the student's user ids
        populate: { path: 'user' }
      })
      .exec(function(err, groups){
        res.json(groups);
      });
```

You can read more about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. It worked and easy to understand!

Comment: And thanks for the resource! I had read through mongoose docs previously, but overlooked the section regarding populating across multiple levels.

Comment: I am glad I could help.